Не работают аннотации Lombok
Использую gradle, Intellij Idea в качестве IDE. Зависимость добавлена, annotation processing включен, плагин установлен. Сама айдия не подсвечивает использование методов как ошибку. Во время compileJava даёт ошибку...






В зависимостях попробуйте Ломбоку установить тип annotation-processor (или как-то так он называется, можно в документации Градла посмотреть) вместо compileOnly.

@Byb спасибо, решило проблему.

У меня в gradle объявлено так
compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok"
annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok"


Спасибо, решило мою проблему.
